# iOS Application Crashing on Launch

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I'm at my wit's end on this one. There are two ways I get my application to my iPhone to test it:

1. I build a debug version, and Xcode installs it on the phone for me.
2. iOSOpenDev packages up what Xcode compiles and sends it to the phone via `ssh`.

Both are crashing for different reasons. For **route 1**, the application actually launches, and when I go to the part of the application that tries to open a directory outside the iOS application sandbox area (`/var/mobile/Library/SBSettings/Toggles`), `errno` returns that the operation was not permitted--the opendir was not permitted. This problem I'm attributing to the application trying to reach outside its sandbox which brings me to **route 2**: I build the application and install it over ssh - it's an automated process handled by iOSOpenDev - then when I go to launch the application, it just crashes.

Here's the console log:

```
Sep  8 01:35:24 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: com.Buford.OpenScheduler [OpenScheduler] (690.10)
Sep  8 01:35:24 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/3GMy3G.dylib
Sep  8 01:35:24 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
Sep  8 01:35:24 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/AdBlocker.dylib
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/RotationInhibitor.dylib
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/WallpaperJPEGifier.dylib
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/WinterBoard.dylib
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: message not found [UIImage defaultDesktopImage]
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/ZephyrKeyboardProxy.dylib
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/libstatusbar.dylib
Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/sandcastleclient.dylib

Sep  8 01:35:26 unknown ReportCrash[15167] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [ReportCrash] (690.10)
Sep  8 01:35:26 unknown ReportCrash[15167] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process OpenScheduler[15166]
Sep  8 01:35:26 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.Buford.OpenScheduler[0x38e8]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
Sep  8 01:35:26 unknown SpringBoard[15105] <Warning>: Application 'OpenScheduler' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6
Sep  8 01:35:26 unknown ReportCrash[15167] <Error>: libMobileGestalt computeUniqueDeviceID: total time for bb to return imei: 0
Sep  8 01:35:26 unknown ReportCrash[15167] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/OpenScheduler_2012-09-08-013526_Bretts-iPhone.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

and the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 43F071CB-E58A-4A1D-BB7B-6D981376E1A9
CrashReporter Key:   c28880d2762136f93b677e2d490a012c08f6f75f
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         OpenScheduler [15166]
Path:            /Applications/OpenScheduler.app/OpenScheduler
Identifier:      OpenScheduler
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-09-08 01:35:26.109 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x317e932c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ee6208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33edf298 abort + 88
3   OpenScheduler                   0x00093f9c -[AppDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] (AppDelegate.m:148)
4   OpenScheduler                   0x00093c52 -[AppDelegate managedObjectContext] (AppDelegate.m:88)
5   OpenScheduler                   0x0008f7a8 -[SchedulesTVC initWithCoder:] (SchedulesTVC.m:29)
6   UIKit                           0x3157ec0c -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 212
7   UIKit                           0x315edb14 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1772
8   UIKit                           0x315ed6b4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 652
9   UIKit                           0x315ed41c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 84
10  UIKit                           0x314eba56 -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 954
11  UIKit                           0x314f0252 -[UINavigationController initWithCoder:] + 42
12  UIKit                           0x315edb14 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1772
13  UIKit                           0x315ed6b4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 652
14  UIKit                           0x315ed41c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 84
15  UIKit                           0x314eba56 -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 954
16  UIKit                           0x314f273a -[UITabBarController initWithCoder:] + 42
17  UIKit                           0x315edb14 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1772
18  UIKit                           0x315ed41c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 84
19  UIKit                           0x3157e832 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 146
20  UIKit                           0x315edb14 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1772
21  UIKit                           0x315ed6b4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 652
22  UIKit                           0x315ed41c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 84
23  UIKit                           0x3157dfbe -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 658
24  UIKit                           0x3167ea56 -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 190
25  UIKit                           0x3167eb88 -[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] + 56
26  UIKit                           0x314b53fc -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 60
27  UIKit                           0x3133e6e4 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 216
28  UIKit                           0x31338728 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 228
29  UIKit                           0x31306abc -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1004
30  UIKit                           0x31306560 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 48
31  UIKit                           0x31305f34 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820
32  GraphicsServices                0x33d48224 PurpleEventCallback + 876
33  CoreFoundation                  0x3760651c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
34  CoreFoundation                  0x376064be __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
35  CoreFoundation                  0x3760530c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
36  CoreFoundation                  0x3758849e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
37  CoreFoundation                  0x37588366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
38  UIKit                           0x31337864 -[UIApplication _run] + 544
39  UIKit                           0x31334cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
40  OpenScheduler                   0x0009413c main (main.m:16)
41  OpenScheduler                   0x0008b6e0 0x8a000 + 5856

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x317d93a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3075eea4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3075ebc2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x317e9cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ea1f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ea1cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x317e9cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ea1f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ea1cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x317d9004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x317d91fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x376063ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37605124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3758849e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x37588366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x32f31c9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ea772e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ea75e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3f0a1d98      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x2fe86988
    r8: 0x001dd800    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x0019cda0     r11: 0x00000014
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fe8697c      lr: 0x33ee620f      pc: 0x317e932c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0x8a000 -    0x9cfff +OpenScheduler armv7  <141a95f4628031e0b5b06f47f18f88f0> /Applications/OpenScheduler.app/OpenScheduler
   0xba000 -    0xbafff +MobileSubstrate.dylib armv6  <d8da1cc9b8ea37cfba03a60549cdac4c> /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib
  0x200000 -   0x201fff +SubstrateLoader.dylib armv6  <825b732151e6379b9cbec6e597a986fa> /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/Libraries/SubstrateLoader.dylib
  0x230000 -   0x24bfff +3GMy3G.dylib arm  <681f7bf53fa5b2ae312f607fbd2c127d> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/3GMy3G.dylib
  0x252000 -   0x255fff  libsubstrate.dylib armv6  <3af5fa8c0a663c82af86669aaf835231> /usr/lib/libsubstrate.dylib
  0x258000 -   0x368fff  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib arm  /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
  0x3e2000 -   0x3ecfff +xyzzy.dylib arm  <4671075692c089ec91d586802a58db9f> /Applications/My3G.app/xyzzy.dylib
  0x3ef000 -   0x3fbfff +Activator.dylib armv6  <22da11ddbca43147a9a7880a0e78c88b> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
  0x485000 -   0x493fff +AdBlocker.dylib armv6  <85025951abf93cd1b904ec6dcdbb8c58> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/AdBlocker.dylib
  0x4a6000 -   0x4d6fff  libpcre.1.dylib arm  /usr/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
  0x4db000 -   0x4ddfff +RotationInhibitor.dylib armv6  <45a8eaf4246e3dce94448d3536968c52> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/RotationInhibitor.dylib
  0x4e0000 -   0x4e0fff +WallpaperJPEGifier.dylib armv6  <29dce2ca76f23ea3a74d77b4005c3b18> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/WallpaperJPEGifier.dylib
  0x4e3000 -   0x4f4fff +WinterBoard.dylib arm  /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/WinterBoard.dylib
  0x505000 -   0x505fff +ZephyrKeyboardProxy.dylib armv6  <07494c9315153ac098783e7ec4f0970b> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/ZephyrKeyboardProxy.dylib
  0x508000 -   0x50efff +libstatusbar.dylib armv6  <fe21097b2cb83481a70c9ab877af55e3> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/libstatusbar.dylib
  0x512000 -   0x513fff +sandcastleclient.dylib armv6  <d138ce2db8b033aba6119acf3d561535> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/sandcastleclient.dylib
0x2fe89000 - 0x2feaafff  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3055a000 - 0x305a6fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x30752000 - 0x30768fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x30769000 - 0x3077ffff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x30791000 - 0x3079afff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3093d000 - 0x3097bfff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3097c000 - 0x30982fff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x309f6000 - 0x309f6fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x30a19000 - 0x30a1ffff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x30a44000 - 0x30a45fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x30bf8000 - 0x30bfcfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x30bfd000 - 0x30c3dfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x31223000 - 0x31246fff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3124f000 - 0x31265fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x3129a000 - 0x3129bfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3129c000 - 0x312b2fff  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x312b5000 - 0x312b8fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x312d4000 - 0x312d5fff  CoreSurface armv7  <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x31303000 - 0x317a5fff  UIKit armv7  <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x317d8000 - 0x317eefff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x317ef000 - 0x31813fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x31899000 - 0x318d4fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x31906000 - 0x3195efff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x3197b000 - 0x319c4fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x319e3000 - 0x319edfff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x319ee000 - 0x31a13fff  OpenCL armv7  <f4b08361179a3f6bb033415b0d7c6251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x31a1f000 - 0x31a20fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x31a21000 - 0x31a91fff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x31a92000 - 0x31adbfff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x31adc000 - 0x31ae0fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x31bc8000 - 0x31bd4fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x31bd5000 - 0x31c54fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x31e24000 - 0x31e2afff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x31e2b000 - 0x31e7cfff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x31e7d000 - 0x31e81fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x31ee0000 - 0x31eeffff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x31f19000 - 0x31f1ffff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x32761000 - 0x32766fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <dc11c5c2cbe73a6288a6094ebf5de673> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x32934000 - 0x32934fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x32ccf000 - 0x32cd0fff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x32d5b000 - 0x32d6afff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x32e26000 - 0x32e5dfff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x32e81000 - 0x32e84fff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x32e88000 - 0x33647fff  WebCore armv7  <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x3364a000 - 0x33694fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f1fbb825def23043830a095b953a9c94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x33695000 - 0x336aafff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x33760000 - 0x3377ffff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33780000 - 0x33783fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x33784000 - 0x33787fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x3379b000 - 0x337f8fff  StoreServices armv7  <6ce256d3cf433e4aa1af8d696bf1f75d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x33a93000 - 0x33b6bfff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x33d43000 - 0x33d4dfff  GraphicsServices armv7  <cb64e146a8ee3fda9e80ffae1ccc9c5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33d55000 - 0x33d8dfff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x33de8000 - 0x33df0fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x33e99000 - 0x33f25fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x33f33000 - 0x33f35fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x33f40000 - 0x33f4cfff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x33fb1000 - 0x33fb2fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x33fce000 - 0x33fcffff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x33fd0000 - 0x3407afff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x3443e000 - 0x34442fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x34443000 - 0x344f0fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x344f1000 - 0x347b2fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34800000 - 0x349bdfff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x34b8d000 - 0x34badfff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x34d1c000 - 0x34d20fff  IOSurface armv7  <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x34d32000 - 0x34d32fff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x34d33000 - 0x34d44fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x34d65000 - 0x34eaefff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x35083000 - 0x351c8fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x35220000 - 0x35224fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x3529e000 - 0x352e8fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x352e9000 - 0x3532dfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3532e000 - 0x353f4fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x353fe000 - 0x35433fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x35529000 - 0x3552efff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x355c5000 - 0x357f2fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <c3098478486032c6aff336fa711c4fc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x358ce000 - 0x359f3fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x35a30000 - 0x35b1efff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x35b22000 - 0x35b2afff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x35b2b000 - 0x35bfbfff  WebKit armv7  <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x35d8c000 - 0x35e05fff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x35e07000 - 0x35e0dfff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x35e17000 - 0x35e19fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x362a0000 - 0x362bdfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x363cc000 - 0x36408fff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x36409000 - 0x3694dfff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x3694e000 - 0x3699ffff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x369ac000 - 0x369b7fff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x36a7d000 - 0x36ac5fff  CoreMedia armv7  <e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x36af1000 - 0x36cd5fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x36cd9000 - 0x36cdcfff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x36cdd000 - 0x36d2bfff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x36d60000 - 0x36d65fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x36d66000 - 0x36d6dfff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x36d6e000 - 0x36f14fff  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x370b2000 - 0x370bcfff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x370f5000 - 0x370f5fff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
```

(Note: there are more binary images in the crash log, but I cut them out due to the character limit)

Here's where the code is crashing:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"OpenScheduler.sqlite"];
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                         NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Couple of questions here:

- Is my assessment of route 1 correct? Is it getting *"Operation not permitted"* because it's reaching outside it's sandbox? Is there a way to get around this since my phone is jailbroken?
- The console log doesn't seem to give any relevant information about why my application is crashing if I use route 2 (build and send by ssh). Any ideas or suggestions on how to fix this error?

---

**SOLVED!**

The issue was that there was a month old .sqlite file in my /var/mobile/Documents directory on the phone. I deleted it and all is working fine now. Thanks Nate for shoving me in the right direction with symbolication.

Comment: In case #2 it looks like your own code calls `abort`. Any asserts in there that could be hit?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson No there isn't. It doesn't even reach didApplicationFinishLaunching: in the app delegate which is part of the frustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that if you just build the app normally (installed with Xcode), it will not be able to access the contents of `/var/mobile/Library/SBSettings/Toggles`.

In the logs you posted here, I see this line:

> Sep  8 01:35:25 unknown OpenScheduler[15166] : MS:Warning: message not found [UIImage defaultDesktopImage]

The `UIImage` class does not have a method named `defaultDesktopImage`.  Are you trying to call that somewhere in your code (or a 3rd-party piece of code that you're using)?

Sending a message to a non-nil object that it does not have a method implementation for will cause a crash.   Granted, I would normally expect to see this in the logs:

> -[UIImage defaultDesktopImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1923d0

But, why don't you at least double check that first.  If that doesn't fix the problem, report back and we'll see if we can give you more help.

You can also [read here on how to analyze crash reports](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html), or [see the Apple video on the subject online](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=317)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The thing that has me pulling my hair out is that I don't call or make UIImage objects for anything. My app doesn't deal with images at all. The second reason for my soon to be bald appearance is that the crash happens before it gets to didApplicationFinishLaunching in the App Delegate, so I don't know how to debug this if it happens before the first place I could put code in.

Comment: @Brett, even if you're not making the call, the OS itself might be doing it (in which case, it would have to be a private API ... which I don't think is the case here), or a 3rd-party library could be doing it ... also not likely based on what you've said.  Have you tried following the links in my answer, to try to analyze the crash?    The 4th, 5th, and 6th lines in the stack trace are in your app, so it would be interesting to know what those lines actually correspond to.  Alternatively, I don't know if you'd be able to post the full-project online somewhere, to let us run it.

Comment: I finally figured out how to get the crash report to fully symbolicate, and I posted both the revisions to the crash log and the code that somehow causes the crash. The weird thing is that I can install the app on my iphone via xCode, and it works fine. If I go by ssh, this error crops up, yet its the same exact code that I'm using in both cases.